# Lag variable by group/time indicator in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data that looks like this:

```
set.seed(13)
dt <- data.frame(group = c(rep("a", 3), rep("b", 4), rep("c", 3)), var = c(rep(0.1,3), rep(0.3, 4), rep(1.1,3)))
dt

   group var
1      a 0.1
2      a 0.1
3      a 0.1
4      b 0.3
5      b 0.3
6      b 0.3
7      b 0.3
8      c 1.1
9      c 1.1
10     c 1.1
```

I'd like to lag `var` variable for all respondents in the group variable `group`. One difficulty is that the groups are of different size, otherwise this would be no problem specifing `n` as the size of all groups. My data should look accordingly (see below). How do I get at this using `dplyr` for example?

```
   group var lag1.var lag2.var
1      a 0.1 NA       NA
2      a 0.1 NA       NA
3      a 0.1 NA       NA
4      b 0.3 0.1      NA
5      b 0.3 0.1      NA
6      b 0.3 0.1      NA
7      b 0.3 0.1      NA
8      c 1.1 0.3      0.1
9      c 1.1 0.3      0.1
10     c 1.1 0.3      0.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a tibble with the lag variables for each group and then merge it with `dt`. Try this:

```
left_join(dt, dt %>%
                  group_by(group) %>%
                  mutate(var = first(var)) %>%
                  distinct() %>%
                  ungroup() %>%
                  mutate(lag1.var = lag(var, order_by = group),
                         lag2.var = lag(lag1.var, order_by = group)) %>%
                  select(-var),
          by = "group")
# output
   group var lag1.var lag2.var
1      a 0.1       NA       NA
2      a 0.1       NA       NA
3      a 0.1       NA       NA
4      b 0.3      0.1       NA
5      b 0.3      0.1       NA
6      b 0.3      0.1       NA
7      b 0.3      0.1       NA
8      c 1.1      0.3      0.1
9      c 1.1      0.3      0.1
10     c 1.1      0.3      0.1
```

This assumes that `var` is always the same within each group

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option. First we nest by group, then we map out the lagged values and then unnest.

```
library(tidyverse)

dt %>% 
  nest(-group) %>% 
  mutate(lag1.var = map_dbl(data, ~.x$var[[1]]) %>% lag(.), lag2.var = lag(lag1.var)) %>%
  unnest
#>    group lag1.var lag2.var var
#> 1      a       NA       NA 0.1
#> 2      a       NA       NA 0.1
#> 3      a       NA       NA 0.1
#> 4      b      0.1       NA 0.3
#> 5      b      0.1       NA 0.3
#> 6      b      0.1       NA 0.3
#> 7      b      0.1       NA 0.3
#> 8      c      0.3      0.1 1.1
#> 9      c      0.3      0.1 1.1
#> 10     c      0.3      0.1 1.1
```